# Terminator (terminal emulator) auto exit on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, terminator

I used **Terminator** (terminal emulator) on ubuntu 20.04 for a long time.
I was trying to customise the Terminator.
suddenly it exits. And after that when I open it and do right-click on it, then it exits.

- I have uninstalled and reinstall the emulator several times but the
  end result is the same.
- I have also undone the customization but the result remains same.

I

Answer (score 1):

I always found the config UI to be a bit unreliable.  It can be configured manually in `~/.config/terminator/config`.  There also should be a manpage for it `man terminator_config`